# PHP. Can i make Reflection use autoload?

Tags: php, reflection

I need to instantiate a lot of classes with Reflection. There are different namespaces with a special classes with same names but different parameters.

Each namespace contain Super class which run other special classes with the same way - reflection.

I can add param to the super class what namespace I should use, but it would be more comfortable if I include in `use` section of my file all classes I want use in Reflection.

Any ideas?

Example (I want to have):

```
use Namespace1\Class1;
use Namespace1\Class2;
use Namespace2\Class1; // same name as in Namespace1


class Management {
   public function run()
   {
      // ...some inits with a lot of params which I pass through __constructor

      $needClassName = $this->getClassName(); // should be Class1, Class2

      $reflect = new \ReflectionClass($needClassName);
      $manager = $reflect->newInstance($user, $database, $errors);
   }
}
```

Comment: We need to see some code. At least show us how you set things up and how you, currently, instantiate classes.

Comment: Why do you need to instantiate classes with Reflection?

Comment: @magnus-eriksson, I've updated my post. thank you

Comment: @charlotte-dunois , I think it is the most effective solution at point of dynamical generated class mapping instead of using a lot of conditions for choosing which class is better adapted for using right now. Because here A simplified exampel of code, in full version it also detect what params passed and how many it can be accepted for the function which I'll invoke after.

Comment: check out the factory pattern http://www.phptherightway.com/pages/Design-Patterns.html

Comment: Suggest to simply use composer autoloading. Reflection is slow and hard to debug.

Comment: @danfromgermany I am already using it. And it doesn't help.

Comment: thank you, guys, I will re-read 'abstract factory' and will see possibility of it implements.